# Subdomain forwarding to another domain

Tags: dns, domains

**Graphic:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZZ8U.png]

**Problem:** `status.renfi.ga` has to display the content on hostinger.com and `renfi.ga` the content on my homeserver

**Question:** On which point does i have to change my settings and how is that record type called?

**Important:** `status.renfi.ga` shouldn't change to `ne.esy.es` after pressing enter (in the browser-url-line)

Comment: I am not sure I follow this.

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: I am not sure. ;-) Let me think on this some. I will be leaving again soon, but will be back in a couple of hours. Perhaps a second look then will shake a few bolts into place and the wheels will turn without grinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ok i got it.
You have to change the settings in **freedns.afraid.org**:

```
renfi.ga -  A-> <dyndns home ip>
status.renfi.ga -Web Forward record-> http://ne.esy.es/
```

Hope this helped :)